# js canvases stacking order

Tags: javascript, canvas, z-index

I apologise if this is not the right place for beginner's question
This is my first search for help in stack overflow and I am only beginning with js.
Disclaimer: I am trying to explore Physics examples from a book and concentrating only in learning about the canvas. I know practically NOTHING about HTML/CSS; just the bare essentials to play in the canvas (so far, I have already balls jumping & collision testing etc).

I have drawn three partially overlapping squares of different colors (red blue black) in three corresponding canvas(es) named as "layer1" "layer2" "layer3" in this order and I can see them piled in their expected stacking order: black on top of blue on top of red.

I have set up a keydown event listener and am trying to use switch to change the stacking order, but have been unsuccessful.

```
function moveLayers(evt) {
    switch(evt.keyCode) {
      case 37: // up arrow
      // what code should go here to change the order of layer1 and layer3 
    break;
    }
}
```

Yes I found it has to do with z-indez, but don't know exactly the syntax needed
Thanks for replying with the specific line of code (I suspect it is just a one liner) or nudging me in the right direction.

Comment: As a beginner, I always suggest creating a fiddle showcasing your problem if you are able to, and pasting the link in your question. It makes it much easier for people to help.

Comment: Why are you using three separate canvases?

Answer (score 0):

I knew it should just one line!
Found out at Style zIndex Property at
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_zindex.asp

solution:

to change layer 3 to layer 1, just write:

document.getElementById("layer3").style.zIndex = "1";